# Damping factor - How to get to these circuits

Tags: capacitor, circuit-analysis, inductor, damping-factor

Do RL and RC circuits have a damping factor? If so, what would be the expression.

Because I know what RLC circuits have, but these others I do not know
Thank you!

Comment: have you tried wikipedia?

Comment: Yes, but I only found cushioning for RLC and LC on the website

Answer (score 1):

"Damping factor" is only used for circuits that have pole or zero pairs off the real axis. You can get pairs of complex conjugate zeros with just resistors and capacitors, as in a twin-T circuit, but there's no way to get pole pairs with just resistors and capacitors, *except* in an active filter. It's necessary to have unilateral transconductance as part of the circuit. All the popular active filter configurations can exhibit resonance, and have a damping factor. The term "active filter" is often used loosely and improperly to include any filter circuit that has an op amp someplace. Unless the circuit is resonant to some extent it shouldn't be called that.

In the equation following the damping factor is delta. When it's 1, the expression has colocated poles at the undamped natural frequency. omega subscript n. When it's less than one there is a pair of complex conjugate poles, whose separation increases as it decreases. When it's more than one there is a pair of simple poles on the real axis whose separation increases as it does.

[image: bandpass filter]

I've never seen an RL equivalent (or complement) for RC active filters or passive notch filters, but I think there must be.

Answer (score 0):

What is dampening factor? One name is ZETA, found in 2nd order equations (and higher). RC and RL are only first order.

Answer (score 0):

> Do RL and RC circuits have a damping factor?

Imagine an LCR low pass filter: -

[image]

The transfer function is equal to:

\$\dfrac{1}{s^2LC+sCR+1}\$

And, if looked at an RC low pass filter you would get a transfer function of:

\$\dfrac{1}{sCR+1}\$

Notice how the term \$s^2LC\$ has disappeared from the denominator?

This tells us that a simple RC filter is NOT resonant. If there is no resonance then there is no damping ratio conceptually.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, but because the pole from an RL or RC circuit in isolation is always on the real axis, i.e. not complex and oscillatory, hence the dampening factor always equals 1.

The dampening factor is,

$$ \delta = \dfrac{- \mathbb{R}( p )}{\omega_c} $$

So, left-hand plane poles on the negative real-axis always have a dampening factor of 1.

---

For examples say,

$$ H(s) = \dfrac{1}{s + 1} $$

pole at s = -1, and matlab lists the dampening factor as,

```
 Eigenvalue      Damping     Freq. (rad/s)  

-1.00e+000     1.00e+000      1.00e+000
```